# Relation between time it take to diffuse and temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature, diffusion

I was reading Reif's Statistical physics. In problem 7 in chapter 2, It says

> "Consider a thin copper wire stretched out along the $x$-axis. A few of the copper atoms, located near $x=0$, are made radioactive by bombardment with fast particles. When the temperature of the wire is raised,  the atoms become more mobile. Each  atom can then jump to an adjacent lattice site. Either to the site on its right or the  site  on  its  left. The possible lattice sites are separated by a distance $L$. Assume that one has to wait a time $τ$ before a given atom jumps to an adjacent lattice site. The time $τ$ is rapidly increasing fuction of the absolute temperature of the wire."

As the temperature rises, molecular motion becomes active, so I thought the time it take to diffuse should be reduced. However it says time is 'increasing' function of temperature. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

A later sentence in this problem includes "*τ is quite short when the temperature of the wire is
high*", so "increasing" seems to be an error with the intended meaning of "decreasing". Unfortunately, I haven't found a list of errata for this text to confirm.

Alternatively, the intended meaning might be "The jump frequency 1/τ is a rapidly increasing function of the absolute temperature of the wire."

This would be consistent with standard [Arrhenius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrhenius_equation) or kinetic theory of reaction rates $$\frac{1}{\tau}\sim f_0\exp\left(-\frac{E}{kT}\right),$$

where $f_0$ is the so-called (very high) attempt frequency, $E$ is the activation barrier associated with the jump, $k$ is Boltzmann's constant, and $T$ is the absolute temperature. Here, τ decreases rapidly with increasing temperature, and there don't seem to be any special features in the problem statement that would preclude using this simple model.